# Solr finding documents in a db

Tags: python, solr

Have a little issue about writing some queries to SOLR. I need to find a uniq document in a solr database by it's field (id). How can i perform this using SOLR admin?
Tried accessing throug URL, something like: 127.0.0.1:8983/solr/{collection_name}/select?id:{necessary_Id} 
but got some creepy http responce.
Can some1 help?
Much obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I have have no idea what a "creepy http response" is, the proper syntax for a Solr query is to use the `q` argument:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/<collectionname>/select?q=id:abc123
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use implicit /get handler syntax on /select handler.

Checkout answer in following post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52276272/2536745