# Solr "real time" get - How to include 'text' field?

Tags: indexing, solr, full-text-indexing

Is it possible to retrieve the "text" field when performing a "real time" get ?

When I perfom a /get request the returned json does not contain the content of the 'text' field.

When I perform a search (/select request) the returned json does contain the content of the 'text' field.

Here is an example where the id is 123:

The search request http://localhost:8984/solr/real/select?q=id:123 returns:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4,
    "params":{
      "q":"id:123"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":9.250275,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"123",
        "filename":"SKMBT_C45212120410351.pdf",
        "file_size":1793774.0,
        "archive_date":"2012-12-04T08:38:12Z",
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "_version_":1611231085639761920,
        "text":[TEXT_CONTENT]}]
  }
}
```

Now the get request: http://localhost:8984/solr/real/get?id=123 returns:

```
{
  "doc":
  {
    "id":"123",
    "filename":"SKMBT_C45212120410351.pdf",
    "file_size":1793774.0,
    "archive_date":"2012-12-04T08:38:12Z",
    "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
    "_version_":1611231085639761920
  }
}
```

As you can see the 'text' field is missing.

Is it possible to have the 'text' field included in the /get request response ?

Note that in the schema the 'text' field is correctly marked as stored:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Real Time Get](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/realtime-get.html)

As per above link Real Time Get relies on the update log feature. So, you will get the latest document for that id. So, If your last indexing process is missing **text** field then real-time get wont return that field.

Check the following screenshot.

[Screenshot of real-time get and update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRFcD.png)